# Atempt to access security API

Tags: blackberry

My project was working fine couple of minutes ago,all of a sudden i run the code and i get 
the error below,i added a class but then deleted it,this is how i got the error and i cant seem to grt rid of it,ive cleaned the simulator and my project and when i debug this is the error i get

Module 'StreamingPlayer-1' attempts to access a secure API.
[0.0] AM: Error starting StreamingPlayer: Module 'StreamingPlayer-1' attempts to access a secure API.

....please how do i fix this,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sign your application! read this...

[Code Signing Keys](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp)

[module attempts to access a secure API](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/module-attempts-to-access-a-secure-API/m-p/210339#M30079)

Comment: even if it only worked like 5mins ago and it has been working since i still have to sign it?

Comment: Hi jide are you gettin this message in a real device or the emulator?

Comment: i am getting this message on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

You get 3 CSI Files from RIM when you ask for signing keys. You have to install all three of them before you can effectively sign your app.